# Convert string to enum in ruby (in controller)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I am creating a webhook route where I will receive a JSON, so I am converting it into an object as follows:

`data = JSON.parse(request.body.read, object_class: OpenStruct)`

And that generates the object I want. This object however has a property that is similar to an ENUM, which has some 'predictable' values
being: PURCHASE_APPROVED, PURCHASE_CANCELED.

They come as a string, so I tried to do the following to convert them

`events = { PURCHASE_CANCELED: 0, PURCHASE_APPROVED: 1 }`

So I want to take the value that came as a string and transform it into an enum, the way I managed to convert the data was:
`data.event = events[data.event.to_sym]`
But the data doesn't become an enum, I can't use some properties like the

`data.event.PURCHASE_APPROVED?`

Is there any simple way to do this within the controller? Or would I have to create a class and specify each property just to have 1 enum?

Comment: Ruby doesn’t have enums at the language level. There’s [`ActiveRecord::Enum`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) but your class has to be an ActiveRecord.

Comment: Btw it would be a _very_ good idea to create a separate class for representing a response. `OpenStruct` might look appealing, but it is too forgiving and with it you will not be able to distinguish missing payload fields from existing payload fields containing null value. And yes, it is _very_ easy to make the response object quack like `response.event.purchase_approved?` (or even just `response.purchase_approved?`) dynamically based on the response payload - it has nothing to do with enums though...